# Holomorphic immersion

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-topology

Is it possible to get an holomorphic immersion form $\mathbb{C}$ to $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ which is surjective?

Here immersion means that $f'(z)\neq 0$ when $f(z)$ is finite and ${\left(\frac 1f\right)}'(z)\not=0$ when $f(z)=\infty$. Of course if you show that $f$ is a covering you get a contradiction, but don't succeed in proving that.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it is impossible, since such an immersion would be injective and so an homeomorphism, which is clearly impossible.
To prove the injectivity, let's consider $A=\cup_{z\in \hat {\mathbb{C}}} \{x \hbox { such that } f(x)=z \hbox{ and with the smallest module} \}$ if there is two $x$ with the same module and same image under $f$ we choose the one with the smalllest real part. Then we easily show that this set is open and closed and hence equal to $\mathbb{C}$ which achieves the proof.